# How to mongo restore from atlas backup files?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongo-shell, mongodump, mongorestore

I tried to restore mongo backup files from atlas.

It's containing some wt files. How to restore.

Backup downloaded from Daily Snapshots from atlas.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you trying to restore to Atlas?  https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/restore/restore-cluster-m2-m5-snapshot/#restore-a-cluster-from-an-m2-m5-snapshot

Comment: Oh, sorry to close the question. Solved this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Solved this.

[link](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/archive-snapshot/#use-your-preferred-archive-utility-to-extract-the-archive-and-access-the-data-files)

Atlas compresses the snapshot into a .tar.gz file. This archive includes the snapshot and the mongod logs.

Once extracted, you can access the data files by starting a mongod instance on the host and pointing it at the extract directory using the --dbpath option.

Comment: For anyone like me looking to read them locally, in the terminal, you want to run `mongod --dbpath ../path/to/folder` and then once it says something like `Listening on 127.0.0.1` you open a new tab in the terminal and type `mongo 127.0.0.1`

Comment: Link is broken..